# spec command not found

Tags: rspec

so first I created a folder and also created a ruby file and first installed rpsc which it said ok installed successfully,  But then when I want to run the spec command it says command not found.

```
Jonys-MacBook-Pro:rspec_tutorial JonyIve$ gem install rspec
Successfully installed rspec-2.12.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rspec-2.12.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for rspec-2.12.0...
Jonys-MacBook-Pro:rspec_tutorial JonyIve$ spec user_spec.rb
-bash: spec: command not found
```

Comment: try `$ rspec user_spec.rb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rspec command is `rspec`, not `spec`.

So:

`rspec user_spec.rb`